# What methods are there to load more ROWS into a View display without reloading the page?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I have a basic View showing 2 node teasers at a time. I want to be able to have a button below it that says load more. Once you click it, it will load the next two. I know that there is the module "views_load_more", but there seems to be a bug with that module that causes duplicates. There is a patch for this issue, but it doesn't solve the problem from what i have tried.

I was wondering what other modules or methods to achieve this same functionality?

I was thinking of continuing to use the views load more module, and just use jquery to detect if there are duplicates and then remove them. But that way seems to be a bit hacky.

Comment: Commenting because it doesn't actually answer the question: I have used views_load_more in a few sites and not had issues with duplicates. If I was going to spend time writing custom code to work around the duplicates problem I would probably spend that time fixing the bug in views load more instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Views Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module is an alternative solution for ajax pagers in views however I haven't used it so I cannot comment on how well it works.

It also works a little differently to views load more so it may or may not meed your requirements.